# IOS switch predictive text view with an input accessory view

Tags: ios, inputaccessoryview

I have an input accessory view above my keyboard and its predictive text view. Is there any way of switching the position of the predictive text view and my input accessory view?

Answer (score 1):

No. The `inputAccessoryView` is displayed above the iOS Keyboard. The "predictive text view" is *part of* the iOS Keyboard.

> You may also attach an input accessory view to the system keyboard or to a custom input view; this accessory view **runs along the top of the main input view** and can contain, for example, controls that affect the text in some way or labels that display some information about the text. [via Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html)

It's possible to programmatically hide the predictive text view via `UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo`, but you cannot place a view between the predictive text view and the keyboard.

[image: input view above predictive text.]